# VS Code can't find python 3 interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pip

I am installing Python 3.7.2 for the first time, and I'm using the VS Code python extension.

When I run `python -V` I get `Python 2.7.10` which is not correct!

When I select the `usr/local/bin/python3` interpreter in VS Code I get this error when running a script:

> bash: /Users/erik/Work/Python/usr/local/bin/python3: No such file or directory

But when I look in `usr/local/bin` I can see that Python3 is there. I'm not sure why VS Code pastes the work directory in front of `usr/local/bin` ?

My first thought was that Python3 should be in the PATH variable so I ran the included `Update Shell Profile` command, which gives this feedback:

```
This script will update your shell profile when 
the 'bin' directory of python is not early enough
of the PATH of your shell. 

All right, you're a python lover already
```

Now, after rebooting VS Code I get a new option for selecting an interpreter:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3`

Is that different from the Python in `usr/local/bin` ? When I select it, I get this error:

> The script isort is installed in '/Users/erik/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.

I also get this sideways related error:

> You are using pip version 18.1. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

But, when following these instructions I get yet another error:

> bash: pip: command not found

All in all, this process and the official documentation seem less than user-friendly? Apparently I'm required to dig deep through my mac's system files in the terminal before even writing one line of code.

Am I missing an essential step here?

Comment: How did you install Python (from [Python.org](https://www.python.org/)? did you build it from source? or are you using the version that comes with your OS)? Have you tried to set the Python path manually by adding `"python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3"` to your `settings.json`? If that don't work, use the path that `which python3` outputs and add that one.

Comment: You can try opening up your .bashrc and add the path that it says is missing. As for pip, you can probably get it to run with pip2 or pip3.

Comment: How did you run python?  Try right clicking when cursor is over the editor window, Select  "run Python file in Terminal".

Comment: @Joey ah, that's where the `Library/Frameworks/` path in VS Code suddenly comes from! (apparently VS Code found that path automatically). BUT, is this correct? Shouldn't this be `usr/local/bin/` ???

Comment: @bashrc hmm, I have the idea that I'm adding paths all over my system. There is a .bash file, a .profile file, a .bash_profile file, and now a .bashrc file? Which should I use?

Comment: @jmh that has the same result, but after having settings.json correct this works too. If I just type `python -V` in the terminal I still get version 2.7

Comment: @Kokodoko Are you running virtual environments?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to change your default Python version for the whole system, it might break some applications that are depending on Python 2.

You can alias the commands by adding this line to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
$ alias python='python3'
```

The `python` command will now refer to `python3`.

If you want to execute the original Python (which refers to `python2`), you can escape the alias (so `\python` will launch `python2` without touching the alias).

---

**Btw.**

```
$ unlink /usr/local/bin/python
$ ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python
```

could also be a workaround for you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use virtual environment for your project
first

`pip install virtualenv`

open cmd in your project directory that **you open in VS-Code** (it's important that vs-code sees this virtualenv folder that we will create)

`mkvirtualenv my_env`

and it will activate it automatically. if not run

`my_env/bin/Scripts/activate or my_env/Scripts/activate`

Then go open vs-code then **select my_env for python interpreter**