# VS Code - issue with Python interpreter

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

All.
I'm trying use Python in VS Code. I've installed Python 3.7 and Python extension in VS Code. I've [chosen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lXOO.png) correct interpreter, but when I tried run my script, it's still using Python 2.7.

I've wrote simple test script:

```py
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sys.path)
```

and I got:

> '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'

I've checked my VS code settings founded there *python.pythonPath* with value */usr/bin/python3*.

I've added Python 3.6 to PATH.

I've read https://stackoverflow.com/a/55182584/11222097. None of the above methods worked.

I don't know what more I can do to make VS Code use the correct Python version.

Comment: Are you running virtual environments?

Comment: Are you using Anaconda Python distribution?

Comment: @jmh No, I'm not running virtual environments. I've installed Python via apt-get.

Comment: @jmh i've installed virtual environments and i've created a new one... still doesn't work.